# Display the only specified priority tasks(high/medium/low) on the to-do list web page

Tags: javascript

```js
const lists = document.getElementsByClassName('task-list')[0];
const radios = document.getElementsByName('rgPrior');

function onClick()
{
  for (let i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (radios[i].checked)
    {
      btn_selected_color = radios[i].value + 'P';
      
      break;
    }
  }
  
  const task = document.getElementById('item').value;
  
  // Add it to the HTML
  addTodo(task, btn_selected_color);
  
  // Save it to localStorage
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
  data.push([
    task,
    btn_selected_color
  ]);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(data));
}

function addTodo(todo, priority)
{
  let entry = document.createElement('li');
  let close = document.createElement('button');
  
  entry.className = priority;
  close.className = 'close-btn';
  
  close.innerText = 'X';
  
  close.addEventListener('click', function(e)
  {
    // Delete from localstorage
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
    let index = data.indexOf([
      todo,
      priority
    ]);
    
    data.splice(index, 1);
    
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(data));
    
    // Delete HTML
    this.parentElement.remove();
  });
  
  entry.appendChild(close);
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
  lists.appendChild(entry);
}

// When the page is loaded, get from localStorage
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
  
  data.forEach(function(task)
  {
    addTodo(...task);
  });
});





// const items = [{
//   value: 'Item 1',
//   className: 'low',
// }, {
//   value: 'Item 2',
//   className: 'high',
// }, {
//   value: 'Item 3',
//   className: 'low',
// }, {
//   value: 'Item 4',
//   className: 'medium',
// }, {
//   value: 'Item 5',
//   className: 'medium',
// }];



//const ul = document.getElementById('filtered-list');
const button1 = document.getElementById('high-priority');
const button2 = document.getElementById('medium-priority');
const button3 = document.getElementById('low-priority');

const createListtask = function createListtask(filteredList) {
  lists.innerHTML = '';

  filteredList.map((task) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.append(task.value);
    li.className = task.className;
    lists.append(li);
  });
};

const click = function click(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const t = this;
  const filtered = task.filter(task => task.className === t.priority);
  createListtask(filtered);
}

button1.addEventListener('click', click.bind({ priority: 'high' }));
button2.addEventListener('click', click.bind({ priority: 'medium' }));
button3.addEventListener('click', click.bind({ priority: 'low' }));

createListtask(task);
```

```css
.hiP {
  background-color: red;
}

.medP {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.lowP {
  background-color: green;
}

.ch5 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <label for="txtAdd">New thing to do:</label>
        <input name="txtAdd" type="text" id="item" />
        <input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="Add List" onClick="onClick()" />
      </form>
      <p>Set Priority</p>
      <p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="hi" id="rgPrior_0"/>High</label>
        <br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="med" id="rgPrior_1"/>Medium</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="low" id="rgPrior_2"/>Low</label>
        <br/>
      </p>
      <ul class="task-list"  id="filtered-list"> </ul>
      

        <br><br><br>
      <!-- <ul></ul> -->
      <p> select to get a specific task</p>
      <button id="high-priority" type="button">High Priority</button>
      <button id="medium-priority" type="button">Medium Priority</button>
      <button id="low-priority" type="button">Low Priority</button>
```

I am doing a to-do list web page using HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I did only up to display the content entered by users with priority bases (high/low/medium). I am not able to do the last section (select to get a specific task).

The main concept is, If the user clicks on the high/medium/low buttons, It should display the corresponding priority list only. If the user clicks the high priority button then display only high priority list data.

High priority (background -red), medium priority (background -yellow), low priority (background -green). Please modify our code, Below you can see my code. Please, can you help me?
(Some of our code is explained by our Stack Overflow team only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const lists = document.getElementsByClassName('task-list')[0];
const radios = document.getElementsByName('rgPrior');

function onClick() {
    var radios = document.querySelector('input[name="rgPrior"]:checked');
    if (radios != null) {
        var btn_selected_color = radios.value + 'P'
        const task = document.getElementById('item').value;
        addTodo(task, btn_selected_color);
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
        data.push([
            task,
            btn_selected_color
        ]);
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(data));
    }

}

function addTodo(todo, priority) {
    let entry = document.createElement('li');
    let close = document.createElement('button');

    entry.className = priority;
    close.className = 'close-btn';

    close.innerText = 'X';

    close.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Delete from localstorage
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
        let index = data.indexOf([
            todo,
            priority
        ]);
        data.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(data));
        this.parentElement.remove();
    });

    entry.appendChild(close);
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
    lists.appendChild(entry);
}

// When the page is loaded, get from localStorage
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));

    data.forEach(function(task) {
        addTodo(...task);
    });
});

const button1 = document.getElementById('high-priority');
const button2 = document.getElementById('medium-priority');
const button3 = document.getElementById('low-priority');

const createListtask = function createListtask(filteredList) {
    lists.innerHTML = '';

    filteredList.map((task) => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.append(task[0]); //Replace key name if you are passing JSON
        li.className = task[1]; ////Replace key name if you are passing JSON
        lists.append(li);
    });
};

const click = function click(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
    //This data you can get either from localStorage or you can create your prefered way. And the filtering data[1] you can replace with key name if it is JSON 
    const filtered = data.filter(data => data[1] === this.priority);
    createListtask(filtered);
}

button1.addEventListener('click', click.bind({
    priority: 'hiP'
}));
button2.addEventListener('click', click.bind({
    priority: 'medP'
}));
button3.addEventListener('click', click.bind({
    priority: 'lowP'
}));
```

I can see an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: task is not defined` with your code (`createListtask(task);` at the bottom). If it task is you already designed in your code, then please let me know the type of the variable.

Output as follows

[image]